# kotlin flow call list item details async

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, sqldelight, roomdb

let us say I have
//roomdb

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Dog")
fun getAllDogs(): Flow<List<Dog>>
```

// getDogDetails

```
suspend fun getDogDetils(id:Int) :DogDetails
```

I want to hit endpoint to get dog details, however room,sqldelight return Flow<List> as Oneshot, I want to call getDogDetils for all dogs async and return the result as `Flow<List<DogDetails>>`

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if you share more details about entity of Dog or schema of your table

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-flow-273acffe5b57 I use the dog model from androiddevelopers example

Comment: @العبد in document there is no schema of DogDetails, and this query 

@Query("SELECT * FROM Dog")

itself returning all dog list containing details of dog. I don't think you need another object for details of dog, you can extract from the same list.

you can still write more details of your usecase.